# Heat radiation by a body in a hotter surrounding

Tags: radiation

Lets say if I have a body at temperature T and the surroundings temperature is t (t>T). Does the body radiate heat to the surroundings or it just absorbs heat?

Answer (score 3):

It does both.  It radiates heat to the surroundings and the surroundings radiate to it.   Each of these effects will be proportional to the temperature to the fourth power: $P_{emitted}\propto T_{object}^4$ and $P_{received}\propto T_{environment}$.  As such, the net radiative losses or gains are proportional to $T_{object}^4 - T_{environment}^4$

Comment: Did you loose a ^4?